# Two Namingstrategies for one SessionFactory in Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, annotations

I am using hibernate 3.5 and Spring 3.0.4.

I have some old tables and some new tables that need to different NamingStrategies. I declare a sessionFactory in spring with a namingStrategy;

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="energyDataSource" />
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <value>
      hibernate.show_sql=true
      hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  </value>
</property>
<property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <!-- user stuff -->
    <value>user.model.UserAccount</value>
 <!--  energy   -->
    <value>com.energy.domain.Selskapstype</value>
 </list>
</property>
```

I want the namingstrategy to kick in for UserAccount, but not for Selskapstype. Is there a way to do this? Either with annotation or xml?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just write your own implementation of `NamingStrategy` which delegates to one of several other strategies, depending on the table name, and then plug that custom strategy into your `SessionFactory`.

Comment: Wow - quick answer! I have tried to make my own NamingStrategy that overrides the                                                       @Override public String tableName(String tableName) {
  return tableName;
 } and that works.. But then I need to do the same with columnname. And that is a lot of columns. So I was looking for an easier way out. (sorry about the formatting of this comment)

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use two different sessionFactories? One for the old tables and one for the new tables? This way, you can set different naming strategies for each sessionfactory.

Have different dao classes for each sessionfactory and inject accordingly.

cheers

Comment: Yes I can. But then I get two sessionFactories for one request. I have to check if the user is logged in with one sessionFactory, and give the energy data with another sessionfactory. With OpenSessionInViewFilter I fear that it will be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up doing. I created at dataAccessContext.xml that is loaded on startup with contextConfigLocation. This includes one of the sessionFactories.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
...
<property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
...
</bean>
```

In my web.xml I include OpenSessionInViewFilter which maps to /*

```
<filter>
<filter-name>HibernateSessionRequestFilter</filter-name>    
<filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Then the other sessionFactory is included in dataAccessContextEnergy.xml which is imported in my spring config energy-config.xml.

Energy-config.xml also includes an opensessioninviewfilterinterceptor;

```
<mvc:interceptors>
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryEnergy"/>
 </bean>
```

So then I have two sessionFactories and two open sessions... I hope.

Is this a good way of doing it? Or will I burn in hell? :-)